# Adding Geometric Network Trace to Map Using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, geometric-network

I am able to run Geometric Network Trace by using following ArcPy script but I also need to add Trace result into the map. Can you please let me know how I can add the result(graphic/geometry) to the map.

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"E:/Utility/Sample/Montgomery.gdb"
# Local variables:
G_N = "E:/Utility/Sample/Montgomery.gdb/Water/Water_Net"
Flag = "E:/Utility/Sample/Flag.shp"
traceOut = "traceOut_Net"

# Process: Trace Geometric Network
arcpy.TraceGeometricNetwork_management(G_N, traceOut, Flag, "TRACE_UPSTREAM", "", "", "", "", "", "NO_TRACE_ENDS", "", "", "", "AS_IS", "", "", "", "AS_IS")
print "Trace Done"
```

Comment: My recollection is that if you run the tool it outputs a group layer into your map.  You may need to make your script run in foreground for it to work.

Comment: I'm fairly sure this has been asked before, in the last few months.  I'll see if I can find a duplicate

Comment: Thanks Midavalo but that code just add the futures into the gdb . It is not adding them into the map!

Comment: Are you running the script from ArcMap with background-geoprocessing disabled for the script?

Answer (score 2):

If running the script in foreground doesn't automatically add the output layer to your MXD, try using `arcpy.mapping.AddLayer()` to insert the layer into ArcMap:

```
import arcpy

arcpy.env.workspace = r"E:/Utility/Sample/Montgomery.gdb"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"CURRENT")
df = mxd.activeDataFrame

# Local variables:
G_N = "E:/Utility/Sample/Montgomery.gdb/Water/Water_Net"
Flag = "E:/Utility/Sample/Flag.shp"
traceOut = "traceOut_Net"

# Process: Trace Geometric Network
arcpy.TraceGeometricNetwork_management(G_N, traceOut, Flag, "TRACE_UPSTREAM", "", "", "", "", "", "NO_TRACE_ENDS", "", "", "", "AS_IS", "", "", "", "AS_IS")
print "Trace Done"

arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, traceOut, "AUTO_ARRANGE")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also define  a Feature class and  fill  it  after  ending of trace and  use   MakeFeatureLayer  to craete  Layer

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r"E:/Utility/Sample/Montgomery.gdb"
G_N = "E:/Utility/Sample/Montgomery.gdb/Water/Water_Net"
Flag = "E:/Utility/Sample/Flag.shp"
traceOut = "traceOut_Net"

# Process: Trace Geometric Network
arcpy.TraceGeometricNetwork_management(G_N, traceOut, Flag, "TRACE_UPSTREAM", "", "", "", "", "", "NO_TRACE_ENDS", "", "", "", "AS_IS", "", "", "", "AS_IS")
spatial_reference = arcpy.SpatialReference('Projected Coordinate Systems/World/WGS 1984 Web Mercator (auxiliary sphere)')
FC = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("in_memory","Q234","POLYLINE","","DISABLED","DISABLED",spatial_reference)
```

add  proper  filed to  FeatureClass

```
 FC = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management("in_memory","MyLines","POINT","","DISABLED","DISABLED",spatial_reference)
for FeatureClass in FC:
    arcpy.AddField_management(FeatureClass, "TableName", "TEXT", "", "", "80", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.AddField_management(FeatureClass, "Obj_ID", "TEXT", "", "", "80", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.AddField_management(FeatureClass, "GeoJson", "TEXT", "", "", "880", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.AddField_management(FeatureClass, "LayerId", "TEXT", "", "", "80", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.AddField_management(FeatureClass, "LayerName", "TEXT", "", "", "80", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
```

do  a  loop  on  result  of trace
then fill  FeatureClass  with  values

```
for sublayer in traceOut :
   layername=sublayer.name
   ld=arcpy.Describe(sublayer)
   layeraliasname=ld.aliasname
   numbeeLayerId=numbeeLayerId+1;
   if arcpy.Describe(sublayer).shapeType=="Point":
      with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(sublayer,("OBJECTID","SHAPE@","SHAPE@JSON"),"",spatial_reference=spatial_reference)as cursora:
           with arcpy.da.InsertCursor(FC,("OID","Shape","TableName","Obj_ID","GeoJson","LayerId","LayerName")) as iCur:
               for row in cursora:
iCur.insertRow((row[0],row[1],layername,row[0],row[2],numbeeLayerId,layeraliasname))
```

now  you can use  MakeFeatureLayer function to  generate  your layer